# Two threads executing synchronized block simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-synchronization

Below is the code where a `Thread` enters a synchronized block, waits for 5 seconds and then exits. I have started two `Thread` instances simultaneously.

The expectation was one of the threads will own the lock on the synchronized object, and the other will wait. After 5 seconds, when the lock owner exits, the waiting thread will execute.

But, in actual, both the threads are executing the synchronized block simultaneously and also exiting at the same time.

> Expected Output:

```
Thread-X <timeX> received the lock.
Thread-X <timeX+5s> exiting...
Thread-Y <timeY> received the lock.
Thread-Y <timeY+5s> exiting...
```

> Actual Output:

```
Thread-X <time> received the lock.
Thread-Y <time> received the lock.
Thread-X <time+5s> exiting...
Thread-Y <time+5s> exiting...
```

Am I missing something here?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyRunnable m = new MyRunnable();
    Thread t = new Thread(m);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(m);
    t.start();
    t1.start();
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + formatter.format(date) + " received the lock.");
                wait(5000);
                date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + formatter.format(date) + " exiting...");
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: please stop using `Date` class. `java.time` package is so nice.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The answer lies in [java.lang.Object.wait(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) whose documentation says:

> [...] This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to **relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object**. [...]

Answer (score 32):

Use

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

[JavaDocs for Thread.sleep:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread **does not lose ownership of any monitors.**

Answer (score 14):

The following quote from the [Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) explains the situation:

> When `wait` is invoked, the thread releases the lock and suspends
>   execution.

Also, only one thread can execute a `synchronized` block guarded by the same object! Calling `wait` in your example releases the lock, thus allowing another thread to acquire the lock.